# C: Incorrect characters are being printed, suspected mem. issue

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, scanf

I am running into something interesting, where weird characters are getting printed instead of what I am expecting. It was not doing this earlier, but I started playing around with the fgets and sscanf and now it will not return to the way it was. I'm guessing I corrupted memory somewhere, or left something in the stdin buffer, but not really sure. Any ideas?

What I am expecting:

```
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*                                                                         *
*    1) What char for border?                                             *
*    2) Add question                                                      *
*    3) Remove Question                                                   *
*    4) Print last answers                                                *
*    5) Exit                                                              *
*                                                                         *
*                                                                         *
*                                                                         *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
```

What is actually printing (as you can see, it's printing a funky y and consuming a space):

```
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*                                                                         *
*    1) What char for border?                                             *
*    2) Add question                                                      *
*    3) Remove Question                                                   *
*    4) Print last answers                                                *
*    5) Exit                                                              *
*                                                                         *
*    ÿ                                                                   *
*                                                                         *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct f_in{
    char outline;
    int lines;
    int rows;
    int num_args;
} F_IN;

typedef struct args_in {
    char in_string[20];
    int t_format;
} ARGS_IN;

void printInterface(char argQs[5][50], char argChar);

int main(int argv, char** argc){
    char defaultQuestions[5][50] = { { "1) What char for border?" }
        , { "2) Add question" }
        , { "3) Remove Question" }
        , { "4) Print last answers" }
    , { "5) Exit" } };
    int commandEntry, exitFlag, i;
    char borderChar = '*', addQ[50], userInp[10];

    exitFlag = 1;

    while (exitFlag){
        printInterface(defaultQuestions, borderChar);

        // GET INITIAL INPUT FROM USER
        printf("Enter the integer value for the command you wish to select:  ");
        fgets(userInp, sizeof(userInp), stdin);
        // VERIFY INPUT IS VALID
        sscanf(userInp, "%d", &commandEntry);
        printf("\nYou selected: %s\n", defaultQuestions[commandEntry - 1]);

        if (commandEntry == 1){
            printf("Please enter the character you wish to be the border:  ");
            scanf("\n%c", &borderChar);
        }
        else if (commandEntry == 2){
            printf("What question would you like to add? (only enter 50 char max)\n");
            fgets(addQ, 50, stdin);
            printf("This was your question: %s", addQ);
        }
        else if (commandEntry == 5){
            printf("Goodbye!\n");
            exitFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

void printInterface(char argQs[5][50], char argChar){
    int i, j;
    int lineCnt = 13;
    int borderLen = 75;

    for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i<lineCnt; i++){

        if (i == 0 || i == lineCnt - 1){
            for (j = 0; j<borderLen; j++){
                printf("%c", argChar);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        else if (i >= 3 && i <= 10){
            printf("%c    %s", argChar, argQs[i - 3]);
            for (j = 0; j < ((borderLen - strlen(argQs[i - 3]))-6); j++){
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("%c\n", argChar);
        }

        else{
            for (j = 0; j<borderLen; j++){
                if (j == 0){
                    printf("%c", argChar);
                }
                else if (j == (borderLen - 1)){
                    printf("%c\n", argChar);
                }
                else{
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. YOU need to keep debugging and not hope other people will do it for you!

Comment: (Don't write, _never_ present uncommented code. Once you figured out where the junk comes from (hint: it is not from garbling memory), try make `printf()` handle string alignment for you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick here when debugging always try checking what happens using the first/last indexes. If you check in:

```
else if (i >= 3 && i <= 10){
    printf("%c    %s", argChar, argQs[i - 3]);
    for (j = 0; j < ((borderLen - strlen(argQs[i - 3]))-6); j++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%c\n", argChar);
}
```

`argChar`  has 5 entries, but you are trying to access 8 in `argQs[i - 3])` when `i=10` (condition is `if (i >= 3 && i <= 10)`). In C you won't get a fancy **IndexOutOfRange** error, you will basically access another memory registry in the location BASE_ADDR+8.

In C the terms array and pointer are almost interchangeably since both specify the **address** of a memory block. Since an array is basically a *consecutive* block of memory, the name of the array is a pointer to the first element. Example: `array[25]` is equivalent to `*(array + 25)` .

Hope helps.

Comment: Wow, this was much simpler than I thought it was. I had gone too far in the weeds thinking it was a stdin buffer corruption causing this. Thanks a ton for this!